# storing function and instances in dictionary in python

Tags: python

In python dictionary, can function and instances of the class stored as the key value pair? I tried to store function and instances of classes as dictionary value but it won't work. Are there work-around methods around it or is it that dictionary is not meant for storing the instances of classes and function?

Just for the verification,

```
# I created a dictionary
 diction = {'god': 'greed', 'hero': 'zero', 'human': 'pain'} 

# and a simple class
class checker:
    def __init__(self):
        pass 

# and created a instance of that class
obTry = checker() 

# and when I try to add this as
diction['new':obTry]
```

it gave me `TypeError`.

Just realized that I was the one doing silly mistake, I should have added it like

```
diction['new'] = obTry
```

My mistake for not paying attention to syntax.

Comment: Show what you have tried and how it doesn't work.

Comment: Without seeing your code, we can't really help you.

Comment: It is just simple. Just for the verification, I created a dictionary...diction{'god': 'greed', 'hero': 'zero', 'human': 'pain'} and created a simple class as ...class checker:def __init__(self):pass and created a instance of that class obTry=checker() and when I try to add this as diction['new':obTry], it gives me typeerror as 'unhashabe type'. Thanks guys for asking. I was just playing around to see it this works because I thought I could store class objects of my wxpython textctrl as dictionary value.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades: Please [edit] your question and put the code (well formatted) there. It's hard to understand from a comment.

Comment: Please update the _question_. Questions on SO must be valuable for the other people who will find them later, and that will make it easier to copy-paste your code to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both instances and functions can be keys:

```
In [151]: def foo(): pass

In [152]: {foo:1}
Out[152]: {<function __main__.foo>: 1}

In [153]: {foo:1, Fake(): 2}
Out[153]: {<__main__.Fake at 0x3e04160>: 2, <function __main__.foo>: 1}

In [154]: Fake
Out[154]: __main__.Fake

In [155]: type(Fake)
Out[155]: type
```

Answer (score 1):

The only restriction is that the *keys* of a dictionary must be hashable.

Roughly, this is to ensure that you can't modify the keys once they've already been put into the dictionary. Because then they'd 'get lost'.

(If you don't understand what "hashable" means, try starting [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys).)